# Default body behaviour in a Grails tag

Tags: grails

I'm trying to implement a tag that must render a default body if none is passed as argument. Here is my first try:

```
def myDiv = { attrs, body ->
  out << '<div class="fancy">'
  if (body) //this approach doesn't work cause body is a closure that is never null
     out << body()
  else
     out << 'default content'
  out << '</div>'
}
```

Then we would have 2 simple usage scenarios.

1) `<g:myDiv/>` Content body NOT present, should render:

```
<div class="fancy">
   default content
</div>
```

2) `<g:myDiv> SPECIFIC content </g:myDiv>` Content body present, should render:

```
<div class="fancy">
   SPECIFIC content
</div>
```

What is the best approach to use in this case?

Comment: Execute body() and assign output to a variable, and see if output is empty or null that render default body ?

Comment: Yep. I tested your solution and it seems to work. It's not the cleanest I could think of and I'm afraid it hides some pitfall. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I doubt you have any other alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I printed out the class of "body" in the tagLib to find out more about it.

```
println body.getClass() // outputs: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$ConstantClosure
```

this is a [GroovyPage.ConstantClosure](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPage.ConstantClosure.html)

When you check for 'body' in your condition it is a closure. If you use a single tag `<g:tester/>` the body will seem to not exist, and you can use ConstantClosure's asBoolean() and it will return false.

```
def tester = {attrs, body ->
  println body.asBoolean()  // prints: false
  if (body) {
    println "body"
  } else {
    prinltn "no body"
  }
}
// outputs : "no body"
```

When I use two tags `<g:tester></g:tester>` the output was "body" So I tried the following:

```
def tester = {attrs, body ->
  println "**$body**"      // prints:  **
                           //          **
  println body.asBoolean() // prints:  true
  println body().size()    // prints:  1
}
```

I am guessing that body contains some return character or white space.

My best solution is to invoke the method `body()` this returns a String and you can call `trim()` on it and check it in a condition with groovy truth

```
def tester = {attrs, body ->
  if (body().trim()) {
    println "body"
  } else {
    println "no body"
  }
}  // outputs : "no body" in all scenarios except when body contains something relevant.
```

Comment: Actually I appreciated the `body().asBoolean()` solution. Also calling `<g:tester></g:tester>` is a nice way to tell "I want no stupid default content as my tag body"

Comment: An even better approach might be to just check for existence of the argument in your .gsp file and if you need to modify the argument in anyway do so in a taglib if necessary for example:  `<div class="fancy"><g:if test="$argument">(taglib stuff or $argument)</g:if><g:else>Default content</g:else></div>".